# Is it justified to consider aggregated ordinal data (e.g., rubric scores) as interval data?

Tags: ordinal-data

My data consists of essay ratings on 5 items (categories) based on a scoring rubric. Each category is rated from 1 (lowest) to 4 (highest).

However, some items are relatively more important (e.g., accomplished writing goals vs. word length). So I gave weights from 1-5 to each of the 5 items(essentially ranking them). Now each participant can receive a maximum of 60 points.

My question is: would it be justified to consider this new score an interval variable, and therefore suitable for parametric analysis?

Comment: Are you _summing_ up the 5 items' scores for each respondent? If yes, it is incorrect. _Ordinal_ data scores cannot be directly summed, be those items weighted or nonweighted, doesn't matter.

Comment: @ttnphns yes that was the original idea. Would getting mean scores be any better?

Comment: Mean is a normalized sum. So nothing changes. If you want to sum (average) scores, you _have_ to admit they are interval. Or abort the idea to sum.